# Show fax number in email (Opencart)

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I'm using OpenCart v. `1.4.9.3` and I'm trying to put the customer's fax number in the confirmation email. I've tried putting the following in the `order_confirm.tpl` template, but no avail:

```
Fax <strong><?php echo $customer_fax; ?></strong><br />
```

Do I need to modify the controller? *I'm still a newbie at OpenCart.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to edit the Model actually as well as the edit you have already done

> /catalog/model/checkout/order.php

Find

```
$template->data['customer_telephone'] = $order_query->row['telephone'];
```

After it put

```
$template->data['customer_fax'] = $order_query->row['fax'];
```